# Java application requiring LD_PRELOAD setting due to signal chaining says LD_PRELOAD is null

Tags: security, java, redhat-enterprise-linux, jvm

I am troubleshooting the failure of a larger java program on a server.  However, I have been able to reproduce the problem with a super basic java program that just outputs the environment variable value for LD_PRELOAD.  The bash script sets the variable (export LD_PRELOAD=....) and then runs the basic java program and the output says the value has not been set.  Because of this there are crashes in the larger java program we are trying to troubleshoot.  The platform is RHEL 7.5.  Does anybody know if there could be some security setting that could prevent the system variable from being available to the jvm?
I have tried on multiple other systems, including another RHEL 7.5 system and have not seen the problem. This leads me to believe it is a configuration on that server that is different.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is interested we found the issue....The antivirus Cylance was blocking the setting of LD_PRELOAD as a method for preventing highjacking the library load process.  If anyone else ever has something like this happen, I hope that is helpful.
Cheers!